# Order of quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I was reading about quantifiers from [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Discrete_Mathematics_and_Its_Application.html?id=XcrKi-kzwLIC&redir_esc=y).

I decided to jot down all implications due to different orders of quantifiers.

While talking about the orders of the quantifiers the author states following:

```
1) ∀x∀y P(x, y) ≡ ∀y∀x P(x, y)
2) ∃x∃y P(x,y) ≡ ∃y∃x P(x,y)
3) ∃y∀x P(x, y) ≢ ∀x∃y P(x, y)
```

However,

```
4) ∃y∀x P(x, y) → ∀x∃y P(x, y)
```

But,

```
5) ∀x∃y P(x, y) ↛ ∃y∀x P(x, y)
```

that is, not necessarily

```
6) ∀x∃y P(x, y) → ∃y∀x P(x, y)
```

However the book does not say anything about other orders.

Assuming all above are correct (if not please correct), I googled for more, but no use. So I was just guessing **if we cannot infer anything firm about any other orders, thats why it is not given**.

Or just guessing if we can follow simple rule: **The implication between two orders of quantifiers is correct if premise contain more number universal quantifiers than conclusion**, that is following correct:

```
7) ∀x∃y P(x, y) → ∃y∃x P(x, y)     (one universal quantifiers in premise none in conclusion)
8) ∀x∀y P(x, y) → ∃y∃x P(x, y)    (two universal quantifiers in premise none in conclusion)
9) ∀x∀y P(x, y) → ∀y∃x P(x, y)    (two universal quantifiers in premise one in conclusion)
10) ∀x∀y P(x, y) → ∃y∀x P(x, y)    (two universal quantifiers in premise one in conclusion)
```

Are above incorrect? If incorrect, are there others? Or the ones given in the book only possible? Can these implications rule be extended to 3 or more quantifier's order?

Comment: so `∀x∀y∃zQ(x,y,z) ≡ ∀x∃z∀yQ(x,y,z) ≡ ∃z∀x∀yQ(x,y,z)`?, so we can take out existential quantifier but cannot change order among universally quantified variables? If yess then same must be true for existentially quantified variable: cannot change order among existentially quantified variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these are almost correct, as in each one you are essentially going from $\forall x$ P(x) to $\exists x P(x)$.  This fails if the universe is empty.  You also use the fact (quoted in the book) that you can commute like quantifiers in some of your examples.

With three or more, the simple count fails.  You cannot go from $\forall x \forall y \exists z$ to $\exists x \exists y \forall z$ or any permutation.  The first only puts a condition on one $z$, while the second requires it for all $z$.

Comment: By commuting do you mean, from this: `∀x∀y P(x, y) → **∃y∃x** P(x, y)` I can have this: `∀x∀y P(x, y) → **∃x∃y** P(x, y)` and from this: `∀x∀y P(x, y) → **∀y∃x** P(x, y)` we can have this: `∀x∀y P(x, y) → **∃x∀y** P(x, y)`.

Comment: Also can we generalize for 3+ variables as: **given implication is true if number of universal quantifiers in premise is greater than that in conclusion and no variable is universally quantified in conclusion if it is existentially quantified in premise**, so that these must be correct:`∀x∀y∃z P(x,y,z) → ∀x∃y∃z P(x,y,z)`,`∀x∀y∃z P(x,y,z) → ∃x∀y∃z P(x,y,z)` but not this: `∀x∀y∃z P(x,y,z) → ∃x∃y∀z P(x,y,z)`

Comment: By commuting, I meant the first two lines that you quote, which say you can change the order of matching quantifiers. I think a better way to state it is that you can downgrade a forall to an exists as long as the universe is not empty.

Comment: Did u say `This fails if the universe is empty.` Because `∀ is true and ∃ is false when domain is empty`? If yes, which one fail, those which I guessed 7-10 or those given in books too 1-6 (I numbered them in question)? ...

Comment: ... Also for 3+ quantifiers, I really want generalization. So along with **bold** point in above comment, I guess: **changing order of like quantifiers is allowed:∃z∀x∀y ≡ ∃z∀y∀x, However changing between unlike ones not ∃z∀x∀y ≢ ∀y∀x∃z, but ∃z∀x∀y → ∀y∀x∃z (since ∃z∀x → ∀x∃z) but ∀x∀y∃z ↛ ∃z∀y∀x (since ∀x∃z ↛ ∃z∀x).** TBH, this is all guessings, need confirming resource/book/link/opinion.

Comment: This is correct.  Just like you generalize commutativity in addition by putting parentheses around all the stuff you don't want to commute, you can put parentheses around everything you are not commuting in the logical sentence and ignore it. And you are right that like ones commute and unlike ones commute in one direction only(statements 4 and 5 in the original post)

Comment: Revisiting this after couple of years!!! Can we say that following are correct based on statements 4 and 5 in the original post: **(1)** $∃_1 ∀_1 ∃_2 ∀_2→∀_1 ∃_2 ∀_2 ∃_1$ (Prefix $∃_1$  of $∀_1 ∃_2 ∀_2$ is made suffix) **(2)** $∃_1 ∀_1 ∃_2 ∀_2→∀_1 ∃_1 ∀_2 ∃_2$ (Prefix $∃_1$  of $∀_1$ is made its suffix, prefix $∃_2$  of $∀_2$ is made its suffix) **(3)** $∃_1 ∀_1 ∃_2 ∀_2↛∀_2 ∃_2 ∀_1 ∃_1$ as $∀_1 ∃_2↛∃_2 ∀_1$